# Setting up CI / CD pipeline using Azure DevOps and also calculating the estimate costing in order to update the client

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops, microservices

I am working on a new software project which is an online job portal just like naukri.com
The whole system is broken into the following software modules:

**i. BackEnd** - This will be a RESTful Web API solution to be developed using microservice based architecture and ASP.NET Core along with EF Core Code First with MS SQL Server. The backend roughly consists of 7 microservices so far. It may increase in future.

**ii. Front End (Admin Portal)** - This will be an angular 7 web application that will act as a content management system and portal for various administrative tasks to be performed by admin

**iii. Front End (User Portal)** - This will be an angular 7 web application where the employers and job seekers will login to post, search and apply for jobs

I have decided to go with Azure DevOps as a tool for project management and CI / CD along with Azure as the cloud hosting service

I am fairly new to the DevOps and CI/CD concepts and the client has asked for approximate cost that may be incurred for hosting the project on Azure

Please assist me to understand:

**i. How to setup CI / CD pipeline for such a microservice based project?**

**ii. How to calculate approximate cost for hosting this project on Azure?**

**iii. What would be the best option for hosting such a large and distributed application if not azure?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -2):

i. There are plenty of examples on how to create a CI / CD pipeline in Azure DevOps with that kind of application architecture (check [this blog post for example](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AzureDevOpsContinuousBuildDeployTestWithASPNETCore22PreviewInOneHour.aspx) for the ASP.Net Core, or the official documentation). I would personally put all three applications (backend, front user, and front admin) into three different repositories with their own CI / CD pipeline. Then deployment could be done either on Azure App Services or in Docker on Azure

ii. You can play with the [Azure pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/). Try to determine what you need and how you want to deploy your application (App services or Kubernetes for example) and if you need something else, like probably a database.

iii. Amazon web services is also an option if you go the docker route. There are probably many other options out there